# How to hide tablix using two conditions

Tags: ssrs-2012

when I try to hide table with below expression it's not working.

```
=iif(Parameters!parametername.Value="ABC" and Countrows("datasetName")=0 ,false,true)
```

Thanks,
Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Count("datasetName")=0
```

instead of

```
Countrows("datasetName")=0
```